# Event Handler problem

Tags: c#, events, windows-mobile, event-handling, opennetcf

I have event handlers for intercepting call logs on windows mobile. The problem is more specific to event handlers in C# rather than windows mobile. I am able to attach and detach event handlers for the first time. The proble is: **I am not able to attach event handler after its detached at least once.** Why are the event handlers not invoked after its detached and again attached?

Below is my code:

```
private static SystemState stateIncoming = null;
private static SystemState stateOutgoing = null;
private static SystemState stateTalking = null;


public static void StartCallLogInterception()

{

    if (stateIncoming == null && stateOutgoing == null && stateTalking == null)
    {
        stateIncoming = new SystemState(SystemProperty.PhoneIncomingCall);
        stateIncoming.Changed += new ChangeEventHandler(stateIncoming_Changed);

        stateOutgoing = new SystemState(SystemProperty.PhoneCallCalling);
        stateOutgoing.Changed += new ChangeEventHandler(stateOutgoing_Changed);

        stateTalking = new SystemState(SystemProperty.PhoneCallTalking);
        stateTalking.Changed += new ChangeEventHandler(stateTalking_Changed);
    }
}

public static void EndCallLogInterception()

{

    if (stateIncoming != null && stateOutgoing != null && stateTalking != null)
    {
        stateIncoming.Changed -= new ChangeEventHandler(stateIncoming_Changed);
        stateIncoming = null;

        stateOutgoing.Changed -= new ChangeEventHandler(stateOutgoing_Changed);
        stateOutgoing = null;

        stateTalking.Changed -= new ChangeEventHandler(stateTalking_Changed);
        stateTalking = null;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I updated code to include class level variable. Also, below answers conflict with each other. If I am disposing object, I must re-create the object when I need to attach event handler. Does this make sense?

EDIT 2: The problem is not with objects or event handling code. I am using LargeIntervalTimer from OpenNETCF. Whenever I am running timer using LargeIntervalTimer, the event handler is not attached properly. Without LargeIntervalTimer, everything is working fine.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is something else. There's no limitation in C# to how many times you can attach and detach event handlers. Maybe post some more code and what the exact issues you're having are...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not really clear from just the code you've given, but I wonder whether it's because you're never disposing of the [`SystemState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa455727.aspx) objects you're creating. If you change your code to dispose of them properly when you unsubscribe, that may help.

Alternatively, don't bother keeping on creating new objects - just create the three objects up-front, and then subscribe/unsubscribe as appropriate.

Comment: If I call Dispose on object, I must re-create the object when I need to attach event to object. Is this right?

Comment: The SystemState objects are class level objects. How will I dispose them?

Comment: @Let me Ask: You just call Dispose on them before setting the variable to null.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the

```
stateTalking.Changed -= new ChangeEventHandler(stateTalking_Changed);
```

code. First, you are not removing the same thing you put in, you are removing a new instance og the ChangeVenetHandler. Second, all event handlers are removed when you run

```
stateTalking = null;
```

because of the Garage Collection.

As Jon Skeet said, you never run the code

```
stateTalking.Dispose();
```

before you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **if** statements.  Place a break point and make sure that you even enter the condition that wires-up the handlers.  I suspect that you are not reaching the code in subsequent calls, likely because one of the objects is not null.

Comment: I am reaching to the condition. I also tried after removing if conditions.